# What regular expression to find strings only in C++ source files

Tags: c++, regex, string, replace

I have a C++ application, I'm converting each string literals and also methods to use the generic type to enable unicode in other words the following conversion is being Done

```
const char* str = "this is \"simple string\""; //=> const TCHAR* str = _T("this is \"simple string\"");
MessageBoxA(NULL, "message", "title", MB_OK);//=>MessageBox(NULL, _T("message"), _T("title"), MB_OK);    
size_t len = strlen(str);//=>size_t len = _tcslen(str);
```

the big problem is that the application contains a lot of literal strings, I need a regular expression pattern to find the literal strings only and replace them with _T(previous_str), I found expressions from the web and many from stackoverflow but they matched also the header includes

```
#include "stdafx.h" // => #include _T("stdafx.h")
```

I need also to avoid strings that is starts with _T( and ends with ) [that is already converted before].

Comment: You're trying to parse a source-code. That's a hell of a task. That's why if you chose the regex path (the hardway) you will need a powerful regex engine like PCRE or .NET. So what engine are you using and what have you tried?

Comment: I use the visual studio 2013 IDE and it hang for long time

Comment: You may still do that in two pass: transform all `"string"` into `_T("string")`, and then transform all `#include _T("stdafx.h")` into `#include "stdafx.h"` (same for `_T(_T("string"))` -> `_T("string")`).

Comment: this may be fine but long, but where is the power of regular expressions

Comment: @ahmedsafan86: In parsing **Regular** grammars, of course. That's where the name comes from. But C++ is anything but regular.

Comment: I believe regular expression alone are not sufficient. You have to write a small python script to do it (using regexp still of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmed this is an interesting question. Let's talk about how we would do this with regex. There are a number of options, here is what I would do.

A. I would process the files outside of VisualStudio so you can use the full power of regex. You could use C++, C# or a scripting language such as PHP or python and feed it an array of files to process, or a folder.

B. Here is a regex that would capture the strings you want into Group 1:

```
(?s)_T\([^)]*\)|#include[^\n]*|"((?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")+)(?<!\\)"
```

With this regex, we want to completely ignore the overall match returned, instead only focusing on the Group 1 captures, if any.

In your test text, the captures are `this is \"simple string\"` and the right `message` and `title`.

This captures the inside of the strings, but we'll probably need them for the replacement, so to include the double quotes, just move them inside Group 1:

```
(?s)_T\([^)]*\)|#include[^\n]*|("(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")+(?<!\\)")
```

C. When calling your language's regex Replace function, instead of directly passing a replacement, you pass it a callback function. That function will automatically have access to the Group 1 matches (that is how replace callback works), and you can manipulate the replacement to your heart's content: for instance, if Group 1 is empty, don't replace (it means we matched the strings you want to avoid). If you have a Group 1, do your concatenation magic.

Hard to be more specific but this is the general recipe I would follow with regex.

Comment: really this is so nice I tested it in my favorite .NET regex online tester http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx and I your pattern will help me a lot, And I Add a part to take L"" in mind, bacame (?s)L"(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")+(?<!\\)"|_T\([^)]*\)|#include[^\n]*|"((?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")+)(?<!\\)"    , Now I can look for which group to replace, thank you very much.